# is there any boot complete event in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there any boot complete trigger event in windows phone 8 ? I have search a lot on google but I could not get any information about boot trigger event in windows phone 8 .

I want to start a background process after phone reboot ,  for this any boot complete intent or boot complete trigger event so that I can start background process. If possible please tell me the way to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

[WP7/WP8 doesn't allow for full multitasking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514064/how-to-run-application-in-background-in-windows-phone/13520869#13520869). As part of that you can't choose specific OS events to triggeryou code. There are fixed extensiblity points the OS exposes through various means you can tap into. For example, PeriodicBackgroundAgents starts up on a schedule of 30+ minutes for 10 seconds. IntensiveResourceBackgroundAgent starts up when the phone is connected to WiFi and Battery. However there's currently no OS extensiblity point for startup exposed to 3rd party apps.

If you'd like to see this feature please open up a new [wpdev uservoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com) request with your usecase. Note, overall device health in terms of battery life, memory and processing capability is always a concern. So make your usecase shine.

Comment: Thanks Justin for very such a nice answer

Answer (score 0):

You have no way to trigger an action when the OS has finished booting. You can only create a background agent, that will be automatically launched by the OS every 30 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no such trigger in Windows Phone 8. Your Background Agent just have to wait to be regularly scheduled after phone is restarted.

Comment: Seems android have much more flexibilty than windows 8

Comment: Because in android there is one broadcast receiver which is fired on phone bootup so that we can easily detect phone is booted ..I was looking for same functionality in windows phone 8

Comment: Actually in "Windows 8/WinRT" there is such trigger, but it's not yet in "Windows Phone 8".