# wp8: How to run background agent during boot up / restart?

Tags: windows-phone-8, background, reboot

I would have a background agent which fetches data for server periodically. I would like this agent must start automatically if the device restarted. How can I implement this? I can see a method when added  ScheduledAgent project template by vs2012. I guessed it should be called whenever phone restated.

```
protected override void OnBoot() 
{  

}
```

But this method never called. I believe there must be some way to get this done. Please suggest me how can do it? Thanks in advance!

Forgot to mention my background agent doesn't run until I call `ServiceAgentManager.LaunchOnBootForTest();` the application. What am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680719/is-there-any-boot-complete-event-in-windows-phone-8