# Can I run an app without GUI on Windows Phone 7, 7.5 and 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

On WP 7 and WP 7.5 I have to develop the app on C#, nonetheless, on WP8 I can develop an app on native C++

Assuming the corresponding programming language, I was wondering if it is possible to run a process or an app without GUI on Windows Phone 7, 7.5 and 8.

Is it possible? How can I do it? Any example around the web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps need to have UIs on windows phone. You can't just deploy straight-up services. But apps with UIs can start background processes. I've expanded in the past on what these background processes are at a related question regarding full background multitasking @ [How to run application in background in Windows Phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514064/how-to-run-application-in-background-in-windows-phone/13520869#13520869)

Comment: And then, can I install a background process and let the background process run on the phone as long as I want?

Comment: Once your app is launched you can use any of the available background execution support in WP8. None of the methods allow for a "background process run on the phone as long as I want". Please read my linked article for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run Windows Phone App without GUI. You can run app with GUI and then run from this app background process or background task.

Comment: Great, I will run an installer and then install a background process to do the job.