# Web service Crash in background wp8

Tags: c#, web-services, background, windows-phone-8

why the response of the web service crash if the app goes to Background after calling a web service? does anyone know a workaround to let web service work in background.
below in the second line of code my app crash
.....

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);//Crash
Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
```

......

Answer (score 0):

when App goes to Background it is put in the Sleep mode, thus, aborting all current activities. To prevent from this you can allow your app to run in background in WP8 settings.

Also, check this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514064/how-to-run-application-in-background-in-windows-phone). It describes certain aspects regarding background support.

Comment: what is the of the capability?

Comment: Do I allow my app to run in background from the phone or from the code?

Comment: From UI it can be accessed via Settings-> applications -> background tasks -> your app name -> check checkbox