# WP 8 Tcp receive message even if app is not running

Tags: windows-phone-8, tcp, messenger

I'm developing a Windows Phone Tcp Messenger as a School project. My Tcp connection works fine and I can send and receive messages.

But now I have a problem when I leave my app or when I open an other app, I can't receive messages. As far as I know Microsoft suspends my App if it is not in foreground. I know the Background agents, but they are called just once every 30 minutes.

How can I receive Messages even if the app is not in the forground?

Thank you and sorry for my poor english

Comment: You can try investigating a "hack" of using location tracking. I think they mention that in this webcast: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start-14-Maps-and-Location-in-Windows-Phone-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure, but i think you cannot. I think you need to do research on how to register with microsoft to let you run apps in the background (like whatsapp). It doesnt allow arbitrary apps to run in the background due to their some battery saving policy. You need to check this out [How to run application in background in Windows Phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514064/how-to-run-application-in-background-in-windows-phone)